# C++ Compare stacks of shared pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, comparator

Let's say I have a stack which holds shared pointers for `int` like following:

```
#include <stack>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<shared_ptr<int>> s1;
    stack<shared_ptr<int>> s2;

    shared_ptr<int> v1 = make_shared<int>(1);
    shared_ptr<int> v2 = make_shared<int>(1);

    s1.push(v1);
    s2.push(v2);

    bool areEqual = s1 == s2; // This is false
}
```

How do I make the stacks compare the actual values pointed to by the `shared_ptr` and not the pointers themselves?

Comment: you don't. access to a stack is limited to push and pop. If you need to compare equality you'll need to use a vector.

Comment: How is `stack` relevant ?  Try `bool b = make_shared<int>(1) == make_shared<int>(1);`

Comment: Are you trying to compare the entire stack and validate all values referenced by pointers are identical on both stacks?  Or are you just trying to validate that the top of each stack is equivalent in value?

Comment: I am trying to compare the entire stack and validate all values referenced by pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::stack` has a protected member `c` which is an instance of the underlying container type. You can make a stack wrapper which accesses that variable, and then compare the contents of the underlying containers as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<class stack_type>
struct stack_wrapper : stack_type
{
    auto begin() const
    {
        return stack_type::c.begin();
    }

    auto end() const
    {
        return stack_type::c.end();
    }
};

template<class stack_type>
const stack_wrapper<stack_type> &wrap(const stack_type &stack)
{
    return static_cast<const stack_wrapper<stack_type> &>(stack);
}

int main() {
    stack<shared_ptr<int>> s1;
    stack<shared_ptr<int>> s2;

    shared_ptr<int> v1 = make_shared<int>(1);
    shared_ptr<int> v2 = make_shared<int>(1);

    s1.push(v1);
    s2.push(v2);

    const auto &s1wrapper = wrap(s1);
    const auto &s2wrapper = wrap(s2);

    const auto is_equal = std::equal(s1wrapper.begin(),
        s1wrapper.end(),
        s2wrapper.begin(),
        s2wrapper.end(),
        [](auto &first, auto &second) {
            return first && second && *first == *second;
        });

    std::cout << is_equal << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Adding declarations to namespace `std` is inviting nasal demons to roost. Especially when those are already defined. I originally downvoted, but the last sentence is redeeming. Just remove the first bad suggestion.

Comment: I agree that it's a terrible solution to the problem.

Comment: Then why offer it? [SO] is meant to be a repository of *worthwhile* knowledge.

Comment: Take off the guns, guys, I've corrected my awful solution

Comment: You have officially earned my upvote. Your original solution made me want to downvote, but the sentence at the end kept me off the trigger.

Comment: might be worth pointing out that the construction of the wrapper causes a copy of the stack. perhaps better if it were named something like `augmented_stack` and used as the primary container.

Comment: @RichardHodges - There's no copy. All the casts and return values involve references only.

Comment: @StoryTeller ah yes, its worse than i thought

Answer (score 3):

I like [@RealFresh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54759649/817643). It demonstrates exactly how "encapsulating" protected accessibility really is. But casting a base class sub-object reference to a derived class sub-object reference and then treating it as one can quickly lead to undefined behavior.

The idea of extracting the `c` member is however sound. We can do it without risk of UB with a simple utility:

```
template<class S>
constexpr decltype(auto) stack_c(S&& s) {
    using base = std::decay_t<S>;
    struct extractor : base {
        using base::c;
    };
    constexpr auto c_ptr = &extractor::c;
    return std::forward<S>(s).*c_ptr;
}
```

Due to how the expression `&extractor::c` [works](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary.op#3), we obtain in fact a pointer to a member of `base` (a `std::stack` specialization), named `c`. The purpose of `extractor` is to make the name publicly accessible via a using declaration.

Then we forward back a reference to it, value category preserved and all. It's a drop in replacement in **@RealFresh's** suggestion to use `std::equal`:

```
bool areEqual = std::equal(
    stack_c(s1).begin(), stack_c(s1).end(),
    stack_c(s2).begin(), stack_c(s2).end(),
    [](auto const& p1, auto const& p2) {
        return first && second && (p1 == p2 || *p1 == *p2);
    }
);
```

<kbd>[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8228ffca9cca49c)</kbd>

Comment: Very clever, but surely this has to be UB, no?

Comment: @RichardHodges - Nope. `extractor` makes the name `c` accessible. Then forming the pointer to member `&extractor::c` in fact gives the type `C stack<T, C>::*`. It's all in the linked standard paragraph.

Comment: Agreed. Just goes to show - `protected` really means `public` and should never be used.

Comment: @RichardHodges - Indeed!